# How to avoid reloading of same data into hdfs at the time of any failure in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, hive, hdfs, pyspark

I have a pyspark program to perform business mapping and load the data into two hive external tables partitioned based on month end date.

**Requested Scenario:**
If there is any failure after the load of first target table and before the second table load. During my reprocess I should not touch the load again on first table and continue with the second table load. Is there any wrapper file can I touch in hdfs location or any other alternative avaiable ??

**hdfs location:**

```
/home/gudirame/user/data_base_db/table_name1/_SUCCESS
/home/gudirame/user/data_base_db/table_name1/2020-09-30/part-001-dsfas.parquet
/home/gudirame/user/data_base_db/table_name1/2020-10-31/part-002-dsfas.parquet

/home/gudirame/user/data_base_db/table_name2/_SUCCESS
/home/gudirame/user/data_base_db/table_name2/2020-09-30/part-003-dsfas.parquet
/home/gudirame/user/data_base_db/table_name2/2020-10-31/part-004-dsfas.parquet
```

Comment: Any solution to accomplish this scenario??

Comment: You can wait for the program to generate _SUCCESS file and then execute the second table if this is generated